# Groovy JSON Slurper

Tags: groovy, jsonslurper

I'm having problems parsing a JSON, because the node name, is in fact a number.
How could I access price?

```
{
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "symbol": "BTC",
            "slug": "bitcoin",
            "quote": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 37237.42069352063,
                    "volume_24h": 23804437123.280674,
                    "volume_change_24h": -14.6968,
                    "percent_change_1h": 0.44040638,
                    "percent_change_24h": 2.01772621,
                    "percent_change_7d": -4.41288268,
                    "percent_change_30d": -22.18199672,
                    "percent_change_60d": -34.78947576,
                    "percent_change_90d": -39.35088126,
                    "market_cap": 705362840851.9242,
                    "market_cap_dominance": 41.8976,
                    "fully_diluted_market_cap": 781985834563.93,
                    "last_updated": "2022-01-28T16:27:00.000Z"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Normally I would use the following sentences:

```
def slurperData = jsonSlurper.parseText(body as String)
def price = slurperData.data.1.quote.USD.price
```

But in this occasion I'm not sure how to get there, being the nodename a number.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `.1.` part of the path with the map index `['1'].`:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def body = '''{
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "symbol": "BTC",
            "slug": "bitcoin",
            "quote": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 37237.42069352063,
                    "volume_24h": 23804437123.280674,
                    "volume_change_24h": -14.6968,
                    "percent_change_1h": 0.44040638,
                    "percent_change_24h": 2.01772621,
                    "percent_change_7d": -4.41288268,
                    "percent_change_30d": -22.18199672,
                    "percent_change_60d": -34.78947576,
                    "percent_change_90d": -39.35088126,
                    "market_cap": 705362840851.9242,
                    "market_cap_dominance": 41.8976,
                    "fully_diluted_market_cap": 781985834563.93,
                    "last_updated": "2022-01-28T16:27:00.000Z"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'''

def slurperData = new JsonSlurper().parseText(body as String)

def price = slurperData.data['1'].quote.USD.price

println price
```

Output:

```
37237.42069352063
```

Comment: Thank you very much Szymon!

Comment: `slurperData.data.'1'` probably works as well 

Answer (score 0):

you can also use .getAt()

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def body = '''{
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "symbol": "BTC",
            "slug": "bitcoin",
            "quote": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 37237.42069352063,
                    "volume_24h": 23804437123.280674,
                    "volume_change_24h": -14.6968,
                    "percent_change_1h": 0.44040638,
                    "percent_change_24h": 2.01772621,
                    "percent_change_7d": -4.41288268,
                    "percent_change_30d": -22.18199672,
                    "percent_change_60d": -34.78947576,
                    "percent_change_90d": -39.35088126,
                    "market_cap": 705362840851.9242,
                    "market_cap_dominance": 41.8976,
                    "fully_diluted_market_cap": 781985834563.93,
                    "last_updated": "2022-01-28T16:27:00.000Z"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'''

def slurperData = new JsonSlurper().parseText(body as String)

def price = slurperData.data.getAt("1").quote.USD.price

println price
```